# Is it possible to create an array of BufferedWriters in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of String keywords which I pass to a method, in that method I loop through the array and perform some analysis, then output some text to a file. I want the name of the file to match the name of the keyword, but if I just create a new BufferedWriter each time I move on to the next element in the array, like such:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(array[i] + ".txt"));
    ...
}
```

then I can't loop through the for loop a second time and still keep what I wrote in the previous iteration (which is something I want to do), as creating the new writer to the existing file erases the existing content.

Any way I can create an array of BufferedWriter objects and then just match the writer that I use for each element of the String array by indexing?

Comment: Don't use a `PrintWriter`, it does not do what you think it does. Instead, use an `OutputStreamWriter` specified with the right encoding, wrapping a `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: `BufferedWriter[] writers = new BufferedWriter[num];` Then populate the array with `BufferedWriter` instances.

Comment: If the file exists then open the file to append content.

Answer (score 3):

[[Moving from a comment to an answer, as this does what the OP wants.]]

`BufferedWriter[] writers = new BufferedWriter[num];`

Then populate the array with `BufferedWriter` instances.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to maintain a list of multiple `BufferedWriter` references.

Just create and close one when needed:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(/*condition if need to create file and write */) {
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(array[i] + ".txt"));
         // do the writings here
         // and at last close it
    }
}
```

In case you want to maintain the list of `BufferedWriter` reference, then I gues it would good to use a `Map` (`HashMap<String, BufferedWriter>`) and the do `map.put(keyword, writer)`.

```
Map<String, BufferedWriter> writers = new HashMap<String, BufferedWriter>();
//then store the writers there

//in the second loop
//and you simply look it up using the keyword
//if the writer exists for current keyword use it
//otherwise create a new one
//I guess it would also be good to go through the map closing all the writers once done
```

Comment: I tried this, but I have a loop outside of the for loop and hence when I run through the for loop a second time it creates a new writer to my existing text file and that erases what I previously had stored. It may be that I was being very inefficient (I'm pretty new to Java), but I created an array of Writers as suggested above and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you could use a HashMap or HashSet to map your writers to a key word.

```
String [] myStringArray = ....
HashMap<String, BufferedWriter> writerMap = new HashMap<String, BufferedWriter>();

for(int i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++) {
  String keyword = myStringArray[i];
  BufferedWriter writer = writerMap.get(keyword);
  if(writer == null) {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(keyword + ".txt");
    writerMap.put(keyword, writer);
  }
  writer.write(...);
}
```

And don't forget to add a cleanup method that would go through and close out all the Writers.

```
public void cleanUp() {
  Set<String> keySet = writerMap.keySet();
  for(String key : keySet) {
    BufferedWriter writer = writerMap.get(key);
    if(writer != null) {
      try {
        writer.close();
      }
      catch(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
      }
      writer = null;
    }
  }
}
```